# make a script available on ALL google docs via a menu

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a script on a specific google document that is activated via a menu I've created. I want the menu to appear in ALL google docs files, just like the native menus do (i.e. "File","Edit","View" etc.). How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you have installed this add-on, is it not already in the menu? `Add-ons > Add-onName`?

Comment: Users have to add your add-on so that they can authorize it. There is no way around that.  A users security is top priority.

Comment: You can't. Some action has to take place to add code to a Sheet. Either the user has to install an add-on or you have to add the relevant code to the Sheet project.

Comment: If you are inside of a GSuite system, the domain administrator can make an add-on available to all users.

Comment: I guess what I need to understand is how to set this script as an add-on and how do I give others the option to use it? Thanks for all the comments

Comment: I tried with no success to enable the script as an add-on with no succuss.. I created a Cloud Platform project, and on apps script linked it via Resources. I configured it in the G Suite Market Place without publishing, and still don't find a way to see the menu on other Document files... Can somone pleas help?

Comment: @YanivAflalo [You need to publish the add-on to be able to see it on menus for all docs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60990177/11551468)

Comment: @RafaGuillermo [Here it says I can share unpublished add-ons with other users](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/gsuite-publish-overview#unpublished). I just don't know how

Answer (score 0):

Seems like using it as an add-on is the solution. I am not interested in publishing the add-on at this point.

### From Google "[Publishing add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/gsuite-publish-overview#unpublished)" how-to:

> ## Unpublished
>
> An add-on publication state. Unpublished add-ons (also called developer add-ons) have not completed the publication process and are
>   not listed in the [G Suite Marketplace](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/). This doesn't mean the
>   add-on is incomplete—it's possible to create and use an add-on without
>   publishing it. You can even share unpublished add-ons for others to
>   install and use.

I created an unpublished add-on, but the menu is not there. This is the relevant question:

[Can't get menu item to show in an unpublished add-on for google document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60970079/cant-get-menu-item-to-show-in-an-unpublished-add-on-for-google-document/60990177#60990177)