# Can't get menu item to show in an unpublished add-on for google document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, menu, google-docs

My code look like that:

```
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen(e) {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
  .addItem("Format Your Text", "autoFormatting")
  .addToUi();
}

function autoFormatting() {
  //some code
}
```

- I have set a project in Google Cloud Platform and linked in to my Google Apps Script unbound project.
- Enabled the G Suit Marketplace SDK and configured it.
- The version is the correct one.
- When I test the script as add-on in any state (installed/enabled/both) the menu item shows under the "Add-ons" native menu.

What can cause this? How can I fix it?

I don't want to publish the add-on at the moment, but only to share it with other users from my domain.

Comment: If the menu item is showing, what is the problem?

Comment: it is not showing in the actual add-on. It is showing only when I use "Run>Test as add-on" on Google Apps Script

Comment: You can't then; it has to be published privately to be able to share with other people on your domain.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, what about this: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/gsuite-publish-overview#unpublished ("You can even share unpublished add-ons for others to install and use.")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*If you wish to share an add-on for Google Docs with members of your domain, it first has to be published. There is no way around this.*

#### More Information:

From the Publishing G Suite add-on [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-gsuite-addons#decide_on_publishing_visibility):

> Private add-ons are only visible to users in the same domain as the add-on publishing account. Only domain accounts can publish private add-ons. They can't be installed by outside users. Private add-ons do not require add-on review. Private visibility is also referred to as My Domain visibility.

[And](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/editor-publish-overview#visibility):

> **Visibility:** Only published add-ons have a meaningful visibility status.

If you wish to have this add-on usable by other people in your domain, you first need to Privately publish it before it can be used.

Otherwise, you can send another user your add-on script and get them to follow the deployment steps to use it for their account.

#### References:

- [Publishing G Suite add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-gsuite-addons)
- [Publishing add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/editor-publish-overview)
- [Extending Google Docs with Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/editors/docs)
- [Testing G Suite add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/testing-gsuite-addons)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, what about this: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/gsuite-publish-overview#unpublished ("You can even share unpublished add-ons for others to install and use.")

Comment: If you take a look at the [Testing G Suite add-ons page](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/testing-gsuite-addons#install_an_unpublished_add-on)  it explains that sharing an unpublished add-on is simply sharing the script with another user and getting them to follow the steps to deploy from manifest.

Comment: I see, thank you. I don’t have the option to install the latest version from manifest, only a versioned deployment. Any idea of why that is?

Comment: They're the same thing, see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments). You deploy aa version from manifest and then install a deployment.

Comment: Thanks. About the deployment- I meant that I don’t have the option to install/uninstall the head deployment. I see only “Get ID”

Comment: For this to happen you have to have a G Suite Add-Ons and [edit the manifest file](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-manifests#manifest_structure_for_g_suite_add-ons). Also, [this](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150724149) might help you with some information.